# what is the difference between given json object in set payload and given json data in set payload with output application/json

Tags: dataweave, mule4

case 1)
I am giving the object in key-value pair directly to the set payload and then giving it to the foreach inside which I've a logger which simply print the payload.

Inside set payload=>

```
{
    "msg": {
               "status": "ok"
           },
    "msg": {
               "status": "ok2"
    }
}
```

case 2)
I am giving object in key-value pair directly to the set payload with output appication/json and then giving it to the foreach inside which I've a logger which simply print the payload.

Inside set payload =>

```
output application/json
---
{
    "msg": {
               "status": "ok"
           },
    "msg": {
               "status": "ok2"
    }
}
```

Now when I run the 1st case I got an error in for-each but 2nd case run successfully. In both cases foreach configuation is same.

And the error which I got is =>

```
Foreach does not support 'java.util.Map' with no collection expression. To iterate over Map 
entries use '#[dw::core::Objects::entrySet(payload)]'
```

So here I have 3 Questions:

- Q1) What is the default output of set payload component when we give object without "output application/json" ?
- Q2) What is difference between above 2 cases ?
- Q3) Can for-each can work with objects also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Q1) What is the default output of set payload component when we give object without "output application/json" ?

There is no default. In Mule 4 the expression language is DataWeave 2.x. If the output format is missing DataWeave tries to infer it from the script. It might not be always successful and you need to add it explicitly.

- Q2) What is difference between above 2 cases ?

Note that your first case is not JSON. It looks like JSON, but it is a DataWeave script, without an explicit output format. DataWeave is generating a Java Map as the output to represent a DataWeave object, ie a collection of key-values.

The second one is also DataWeave but the output that is generated from executing the DataWeave script is explicitly a JSON object, with the media type set also to application/json, so following message processors in the flow know how they should try to parse it.

- Q3) Can for-each can work with objects also ?

Depending on the specific implementation class it might work, but in general assume that no. In this case the first one is a Map which is not iterable. The error message tells you the expression to iterate over entries in the Map if you want to do that. I'm not really sure of why the JSON object is iterated with foreach. It may be a feature of the JSON parser implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Things getting more clear now.